# How to recognise the 'T' character correctly within this ISO 8601 date in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, iso8601

I have the following string with the 'T' seperator - how do change the `$format` var correctly to take into account the 'T' within the `$datestring`?

```
$datestring = '2018-12-30T11:30:00';
$format = 'Y-m-dG:i:s';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $datestring);
var_dump($date); // currently returns false rather than an object
```

Comment: $format = 'Y-m-d\TG:i:s';

Comment: ... isn't it just an ISO 8601 formatted date? e.g `$format = 'c';`

Comment: $date = new DateTime($datestring); . Since your $datestring does not embed a timezone, the date will be in your server's timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape characters in the formats (`\T`):

```
$datestring = '2018-12-30T11:30:00';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TG:i:s', $datestring);

var_dump($date);
// object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-12-30 11:30:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }
```

If you also need to validate the date you can use [`DateTime::getLastErrors`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php):

```
if (!empty(DateTime::getLastErrors()['warning_count'])) {
    echo 'Date <b>' . $datestring . '</b> is invalid.<br>';
}
```

Because dates like `2018-15-46T29:63:89` would return an object but aren't valid.

Comment: @Zabs So using this you could forget about the regex you asked about in your previous question and do the validation as part of that creation of the DateTime object

Comment: +1 Bit annoyed really. I had a very similiar answer for OP's previous question and it got Dupped just a second before I pressed the Submit Your Answer button :) :)

Comment: Might be worth looking at `['error_count']` as well as warnings

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh I hesitated to post this answer on his previous question too. Yep I'm only looking at `['warning_count']` here (but OP could `print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors())` if he wants !)

Comment: I thought you may have also seen his previous question :) Great Minds :):)